# WSO2 ESB - MD5 of a Property String

Tags: xpath, md5, wso2-esb

How can I convert a String property with MD5 in WSO2 ESB and set it as a header for a service call.

I have tried with what is said in this link

https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/XPath_Expressions_Module#The_digest.28.29_Function.

```
<property expression="xf:digest('abc', 'MD5', 'hex')"
name="md5_conv" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xquery-functions" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
```

but the below error comes up in the logs.

```
 Evaluation of the XPath expression xf:digest('abc', 'MD5', 'hex') resulted in an error {org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath}
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot find a matching 3-argument function named {http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xquery-functions}digest()
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.grumble(ExpressionParser.java:263)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.grumble(ExpressionParser.java:226)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.reportMissingFunction(ExpressionParser.java:2462)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.parseFunctionCall(ExpressionParser.java:2379)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.parseBasicStep(ExpressionParser.java:1731)
```

will be pleased if anyone can help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Script mediator with JavaScript language for  convert string value to MD5 as follow...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="MD5withScriptMediator"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <script language="js">var MD5 = function (string) {
    function RotateLeft(lValue, iShiftBits) {
        return (lValue&lt;&lt;iShiftBits) | (lValue&gt;&gt;&gt;(32-iShiftBits));
    }

    function AddUnsigned(lX,lY) {
        var lX4,lY4,lX8,lY8,lResult;
        lX8 = (lX &amp; 0x80000000);
        lY8 = (lY &amp; 0x80000000);
        lX4 = (lX &amp; 0x40000000);
        lY4 = (lY &amp; 0x40000000);
        lResult = (lX &amp; 0x3FFFFFFF)+(lY &amp; 0x3FFFFFFF);
        if (lX4 &amp; lY4) {
            return (lResult ^ 0x80000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
        }
        if (lX4 | lY4) {
            if (lResult &amp; 0x40000000) {
                return (lResult ^ 0xC0000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
            } else {
                return (lResult ^ 0x40000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
            }
        } else {
            return (lResult ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
        }
     }

     function F(x,y,z) { return (x &amp; y) | ((~x) &amp; z); }

     function G(x,y,z) { return (x &amp; z) | (y &amp; (~z)); }

     function H(x,y,z) { return (x ^ y ^ z); }

    function I(x,y,z) { return (y ^ (x | (~z))); }

    function FF(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
        a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(F(b, c, d), x), ac));
        return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
    };

    function GG(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
        a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(G(b, c, d), x), ac));
        return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
    };

    function HH(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
        a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(H(b, c, d), x), ac));
        return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
    };

    function II(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
        a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(I(b, c, d), x), ac));
        return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
    };

    function ConvertToWordArray(string) {
        var lWordCount;
        var lMessageLength = string.length;
        var lNumberOfWords_temp1=lMessageLength + 8;
        var lNumberOfWords_temp2=(lNumberOfWords_temp1-(lNumberOfWords_temp1 % 64))/64;
        var lNumberOfWords = (lNumberOfWords_temp2+1)*16;
        var lWordArray=Array(lNumberOfWords-1);
        var lBytePosition = 0;
        var lByteCount = 0;
        while ( lByteCount &lt; lMessageLength ) {
            lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
            lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
            lWordArray[lWordCount] = (lWordArray[lWordCount] | (string.charCodeAt(lByteCount)&lt;&lt;lBytePosition));
            lByteCount++;
        }
        lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
        lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
        lWordArray[lWordCount] = lWordArray[lWordCount] | (0x80&lt;&lt;lBytePosition);
        lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-2] = lMessageLength&lt;&lt;3;
        lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-1] = lMessageLength&gt;&gt;&gt;29;
        return lWordArray;
    };

    function WordToHex(lValue) {
        var WordToHexValue="",WordToHexValue_temp="",lByte,lCount;
        for (lCount = 0;lCount&lt;=3;lCount++) {
            lByte = (lValue&gt;&gt;&gt;(lCount*8)) &amp; 255;
            WordToHexValue_temp = "0" + lByte.toString(16);
            WordToHexValue = WordToHexValue + WordToHexValue_temp.substr(WordToHexValue_temp.length-2,2);
        }
        return WordToHexValue;
    };

    function Utf8Encode(string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
        var utftext = "";
        for (var n = 0; n &lt; string.length; n++) {
            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
            if (c &lt; 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if((c &gt; 127) &amp;&amp; (c &lt; 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c &gt;&gt; 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c &amp; 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c &gt;&gt; 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c &gt;&gt; 6) &amp; 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c &amp; 63) | 128);
            }
        }
        return utftext;
    };
    var x=Array();
    var k,AA,BB,CC,DD,a,b,c,d;
    var S11=7, S12=12, S13=17, S14=22;
    var S21=5, S22=9 , S23=14, S24=20;
    var S31=4, S32=11, S33=16, S34=23;
    var S41=6, S42=10, S43=15, S44=21;
    string = Utf8Encode(string);
    x = ConvertToWordArray(string);
    a = 0x67452301; b = 0xEFCDAB89; c = 0x98BADCFE; d = 0x10325476;
    for (k=0;k&lt;x.length;k+=16) {
        AA=a; BB=b; CC=c; DD=d;
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S11,0xD76AA478);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+1], S12,0xE8C7B756);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S13,0x242070DB);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+3], S14,0xC1BDCEEE);
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S11,0xF57C0FAF);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+5], S12,0x4787C62A);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S13,0xA8304613);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+7], S14,0xFD469501);
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S11,0x698098D8);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+9], S12,0x8B44F7AF);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S13,0xFFFF5BB1);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+11],S14,0x895CD7BE);
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S11,0x6B901122);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+13],S12,0xFD987193);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S13,0xA679438E);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+15],S14,0x49B40821);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S21,0xF61E2562);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+6], S22,0xC040B340);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S23,0x265E5A51);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+0], S24,0xE9B6C7AA);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S21,0xD62F105D);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+10],S22,0x2441453);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S23,0xD8A1E681);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+4], S24,0xE7D3FBC8);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S21,0x21E1CDE6);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+14],S22,0xC33707D6);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S23,0xF4D50D87);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+8], S24,0x455A14ED);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S21,0xA9E3E905);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+2], S22,0xFCEFA3F8);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S23,0x676F02D9);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+12],S24,0x8D2A4C8A);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S31,0xFFFA3942);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+8], S32,0x8771F681);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S33,0x6D9D6122);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+14],S34,0xFDE5380C);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S31,0xA4BEEA44);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+4], S32,0x4BDECFA9);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S33,0xF6BB4B60);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+10],S34,0xBEBFBC70);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S31,0x289B7EC6);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+0], S32,0xEAA127FA);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S33,0xD4EF3085);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+6], S34,0x4881D05);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S31,0xD9D4D039);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+12],S32,0xE6DB99E5);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S33,0x1FA27CF8);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+2], S34,0xC4AC5665);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S41,0xF4292244);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+7], S42,0x432AFF97);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S43,0xAB9423A7);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+5], S44,0xFC93A039);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S41,0x655B59C3);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+3], S42,0x8F0CCC92);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S43,0xFFEFF47D);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+1], S44,0x85845DD1);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S41,0x6FA87E4F);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+15],S42,0xFE2CE6E0);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S43,0xA3014314);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+13],S44,0x4E0811A1);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S41,0xF7537E82);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+11],S42,0xBD3AF235);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S43,0x2AD7D2BB);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+9], S44,0xEB86D391);
        a=AddUnsigned(a,AA);
        b=AddUnsigned(b,BB);
        c=AddUnsigned(c,CC);
        d=AddUnsigned(d,DD);
    }
    var temp = WordToHex(a)+WordToHex(b)+WordToHex(c)+WordToHex(d);
    return temp.toLowerCase();
}
mc.setPayloadXML(
        &lt;hash&gt;
           &lt;hashValue&gt;{MD5("lolo")}&lt;/hashValue&gt;
           &lt;/hash&gt;);</script>
         <log level="custom">
            <property expression="$body" name="HASH..."/>
         </log>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

For more information about Script Mediator follow this link https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Script+Mediator

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was helpful, I achieved the same with a class mediator. I was expecting something with similar to a xpath function, but it seems either class or script mediator is the way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke Java class from a Script Mediator, in your case the org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils class :

```
<script description="plScript" language="js"><![CDATA[var prop_to_hash_var = mc.getProperty('prop_to_hash');
    var hashcode = Packages.org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(prop_to_hash_var); 
    mc.setProperty('hashcode', hashcode);]]></script>
```